# Python 3.x - Return a PDF to the browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

The following code read a pdf file from filesystem and send it to the browser and works fine in python 2.7.x. Right now i am in the process of upgrading to 3.x. and it stuck here with an error "Failed to load PDF document" on the browser. please help identify what is wrong. thanks.

```
 def sendPDFfile(self, pdfname):
     with open(pdfname, 'rb') as f:
         # retrieve stdout as a binary file object
         output = getattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer', sys.stdout)
         output.write(b"Content-type: application/pdf\n\n")

         output.write(b"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s\n"%(pdfname))
         sys.stdout.flush()
         pdf = f.read()
         output.write(pdf)

     return
```

the setup is python CGI running under apache2 in ubuntu 16LTS.

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in Apache Logs (hopefully a stacktrace)

Comment: I am trying to generate an pdf using latex and then send the generated pdf to browser. the error is that on the browser with "Failed to load PDF document". No apache error, since on the server side, everything returned smoothly.  I debugged on the browser and the response is different than the 2.7 return. so I guess this is something related to the 3.x format changes. but I do not know how to solve them. Thanks.

Comment: the error came back with the following message:Invalid or corrupted PDF file.
PDF.js v2.0.775 (build: 20cd1b35)
Message: Invalid PDF structure